# Manually insert User in ELMAH

Tags: sql, sql-server, logging, elmah

I've been trying to integrated ELMAH in my application, a website whose backend calls an API. So far it's quite easy and now I'm trying to use its database capability. It is inserting rows in my database with no problems, however when it passes thru the API's source code, the User column becomes null. Is there a way to manually add the user data each time ELMAH inserts a new row?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't understand why people keep downvoting this question. Setting the user on all ELMAH errors is a perfectly valid question and can be achieved by using error filtering, as explained in my blog post: [Enrich ELMAH errors using error filtering hook](https://blog.elmah.io/enrich-elmah-errors-using-error-filtering-hook/).

To sum up, you need to implement the `ErrorLog_Filtering` method and set the `User` property manually:

```
void ErrorLog_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs args)
{
    var httpContext = args.Context as HttpContext;
    if (httpContext != null)
    {
        var error = new Error(args.Exception, httpContext);
        error.User = GetUserFromDatabase();
        ErrorLog.GetDefault(httpContext).Log(error);
        args.Dismiss();
    }
}
```